# Xcode fullscreen window without titlebar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, window, titlebar

I would like to create a full screen application (mac) but eventhough I have the window fullscreen;
`[window setFrame:[window frameRectForContentRect:[[window screen] frame]]display:YES animate:YES];`

I can't get rid of the title bar? Can you change the above code to make the window without a titlebar or do you have to do it completely different? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CocoaWithLove has a good article about it:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/08/animating-window-to-fullscreen-on-mac.html

```
fullscreenWindow = [[FullscreenWindow alloc]
    initWithContentRect:[mainWindow contentRectForFrameRect:[mainWindow frame]]
    styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
    backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
    defer:YES
    screen:[mainWindow screen]];
[fullscreenWindow setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel];
[fullscreenWindow setContentView:[mainWindow contentView]];
[fullscreenWindow setTitle:[mainWindow title]];
[fullscreenWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

Comment: That's not working :(, I read that website before I posted the question... I'm using Xcode 4 and I'm not sure if it's me doing something wrong or if Xcode just wont do it??? Thanks for your answer though :)

Answer (score 1):

I successfully placed the window over the titlebar using the window level `NSScreenSaverWindowLevel`, instead of `NSFloatingWindowLevel` suggested in Macmade's answer.

```
fullscreenWindow = [[NSWindow alloc]
                    initWithContentRect:[[NSScreen mainScreen] frame]
                    styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                    backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                    defer:YES];
[fullscreenWindow setLevel:NSScreenSaverWindowLevel];
// Perform further configuration here, e.g. setTitle, setBackgroundColor etc.
[fullscreenWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```